# How does nodeJS handle concurrent requests if business logic takes too much time to execute (2000ms)

Tags: node.js, web-applications, concurrency, server

When I start nodeJS application with below code and fire  http://localhost:3222/ from my browser ,app takes more than 2000ms to return the response.

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end(fib(40).toString());
}).listen(3222, '127.0.0.1');


function fib(n) {
  if (n <= 1) {
    return n;
  }
  return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
```

then I tried to access the url concurrently using Apache bench , I noticed request are executed in serious manner rather than concurrent manner.

```
>ab -n 3 -c 1 http://localhost:3222/ 
 1724ms (longest request)
```

Fired 3 request in serious manner ,each taken 1713ms on average and max time is 1724ms

```
>ab -n 3 -c 3 http://localhost:3222/
 5195ms (longest request)
```

Fired 3 request in concurrent manner ,each taken 3483ms on average and max time is 5195ms.

Above timings clearly shows that requests are not executed concurrently by node server.

My questions is,how these kind of scenarios should be handled in production nodeJS applications?

Note: code given is just for representational purpose, I'm interested in knowing how to handle time consuming , complex business logic in nodeJS app with out blocking the main thread.

Comment: Were you able to find the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: @Gowrish, yea, by default node JS uses only one main thread to handle all the request, so it process everything in sequential manner, we have to have multiple instance to handle or we have to explicitly create separate thread to handle time consuming operations

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your test case is: Node.js is single threaded. Asynchronous functions are used for non-blocking I/O: you can wait for a database query or file write etc. to finish and do some other things meanwhile. But if you got some code that takes a long time to execute, all other actions are postponed until this code execution finishs.

You could start multiple instances of your node.js application and do some loadbalancing with haproxy or similar programs. But the only real solution would be to decouple the calculation from your request processing.